# Error during logging in to Salesforce using Axis2

Tags: login

I am trying to log into my salesforce instance using axis2 using the following code

```
        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
        Options options = new Options();
        options.setTo(new EndpointReference("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/41.0"));
        options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        options.setAction(new QName("partner.soap.sforce.com", "login").toString());
        options.setProperty(Constants.Configuration.MESSAGE_TYPE, "request");
        client.setOptions(options);

        final String ENV_END = "</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
        final String ENV_START = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' "
                                        + "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " + "xmlns:urn='urn:partner.soap.sforce.com'><soapenv:Body>";
        String xml = ENV_START + "  <urn:login>" + "    <urn:username>" + "<username>" + "</urn:username>" + "    <urn:password>" + "<password>" + "</urn:password>"
                + "  </urn:login>" + ENV_END;
        StringReader in = new StringReader(xml);
        OMElement root = OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(in).getDocumentElement();

        OMElement response = client.sendReceive(root);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
```

Here 
ServiceClient -> org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient

Options -> org.apache.axis2.client.Options

OMBuilder -> org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement

OMXMLBuilderFactory -> org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory

I am getting the following error :

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:531)
at com.tibco.bw.palette.salesforce.runtime.SalesforceUpdateActivity.main(SalesforceUpdateActivity.java:85)
```

What is going wrong here? When I do login why does it need to reset the url

Comment: Once authenticated at https://login.salesforce.com, you will be given back the URL of the instance your org is located on e.g. https://na46.salesforce.com and you must tell axis2 to go there.

Comment: @KeithC I am trying to do a login here. Why is it saying destinatuin url not reset during login. During login I will obviously hit login.salesforce.com and then obtain the server url where i have to send following requests. My question is am I not setting some parameter for login request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the API doc : [ServiceClient.sendReceive(OMElement)](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/org/apache/axis2/client/ServiceClient.html#sendReceive(org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement))
 I found out that sendReceive takes the OMElement and packages it inside a SoapEnvelope.

I was giving an OMElement that already contained the SoapEnvelope. So basically what was being sent out was a login request inside two nested Soap envelopes. This was causing the error.

The correct way to pass OMElement would be :

```
            ServiceClient client;
            try {
                client = new ServiceClient();
                Options options = client.getOptions();
                options.setTo(new EndpointReference("https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/41.0"));
                client.setOptions(options);

                String xml ="<urn:login xmlns:urn='urn:partner.soap.sforce.com'><urn:username>username</urn:username><urn:password>password</urn:password></urn:login>";
                StringReader in = new StringReader(xml);
                OMElement root = OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(in).getDocumentElement();


                OMElement response = client.sendReceive(root);
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```